# MapBox userTrackingMode not working correctly on Android

Tags: android, react-native, mapbox-gl, react-native-maps

I'm creating a react-native app using https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl, I have set 'userTrackingMode={Mapbox.UserTrackingModes.FollowWithHeading}'. In iOS I can see pulsating point to track user location but in Android user location is denoting by just a point. How can I get pulsating point in Android as well.

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox has different native implementations for these platforms. It just exposes those implementations in https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl. Is there any way to override the UI of point showing user location?